# How to get truly random numbers after seed set in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For part of my code i need to get 'random' numbers that are the same every time that the code is run, and use `random.seed(0)` to make sure that the same numbers are returned each time. However, at a separate part of the code, i wish to have numbers that vary each time the code is run. Once the seed has been set though, each time any of the random functions are called, the numbers that they return are always the same. How is it possible to combine pre-determined random numbers, with random numbers?

Comment: By using two different PRNG-objects (sometimes called streams). One constant-seeded; one seeded by time or external entropy, depending on the use-case. Hint: ```r = random.Random()```. Remark: this is simpler and more performant compared to get/set internal-states between different uses.

Comment: Thanks Sascha - if this was an actual 'answer' i would mark it as the best one for sure!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getstate` and `setstate`, something along the lines of

```
import random

state = random.getstate()  # saving the current state of the generator

random.seed(0)
random.randint(1, 10)

# some more fiddling with random
# ...

random.setstate(state)  # restore the original state
```

Info from the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.getstate